# Powershell convert number to date and save it

Tags: powershell

I am curious if it's possible to convert numbers to data. In below example the script would ask sth like this :

```
How long user will be active: <add number 30 - meaning for 30 days>
```

So there must be a variable that holds a current date and add days based on numbers from the input nd, for example, save these data to file. I would create a second script that reads this file and remove users if current days are equal do the current date.

I am not sure about conversion from adding days like this :

```
current-date + 30 days = date_in_thefuture :)
```

any example or where i should look ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$numberofdays = 30
$Temp = (Get-date).AddDays($numberofdays)
```

Powershell has functions like Get-Date that gives methods such as AddDays() that allows you to do what you are looking for.

[Microsoft documentation on Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7)